# Checking if a view has view blocks

Tags: views

I created a view page; it displays titles and images from the photoset content type. Some of these nodes have a view block.

How can I highlight items on general page with view blocks?
For me it's enough to add some classes to these items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your views display style to **unformatted** and add preprocess function into your template.php, smthng like

```
function theme_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$vars) {
  $view = $vars['view'];
  $rows = $vars['rows'];

foreach ($vars['view']->result as $id => $row) {

    if ( in this place add your if statement ) {
      $vars['classes_array'][$id] .= ' added_extra_class';
    }  
  }
}
```

You can check for every row needed condition

Comment: Another alternative would be editing the template that view block uses. You can scan for templates used and modify the one based on your need.